# steps followed by django syncdb

Tags: python, django

How django syncdb works ?

In my project, I have placed the admins.py in the project root folder.

Here is the folder structure

```
src
 |
 ----proj1
 |    |
 |    -------- settings.py
 |    -------- urls.py
 |
 ----forum
      |
      -------- admins.py
      -------- models.py
      -------- views.py
```

Here forum is a django app. and proj1 is the root.

When I try to do the syncdb, it gives the following output.

```
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)
```

Can anyone tell me how this syncdb works ( what is the sequence of steps it performs) to create the database ? Here, its not creating the tables according to forum->models.py. Should I mention anywhere else except INSTALLED_APPS and admin.site.register() ?

Comment: Is there anything that the [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py) can't tell you?

Comment: I didn't go through the source code. After getting a -1 here, I realized I should have gone through the source code.

Comment: `admins.py` should be `admin.py`; and `syncdb` will not alter existing tables, it only creates new ones.

Comment: I think this means that, while the database was successfully installed, there's no data in any of the tables.

Answer (score 2):

[Syncdb](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#syncdb) basically Creates the database tables for all apps, and loads any "fixtures" (initial data) that may be required to be loaded for the application.

Example, you might have "Categories" of a particular object a required field, which the user cannot change. You can load those as fixtures.

The message `Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)` indicates that for this particular model, there were no fixtures provided.

You can read more about [fixtures here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/#providing-initial-data-for-models)

When you look at the [source for syncdb](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py), you can see that the tables are created, and then `load_initial_data` is called.

Comment: I wanted to know the sequence it follows to create the ddls. Because in this scenario, its not creating the tables for forum->models.py.

Comment: yes, its in installed apps. And also in admin.py, I have coded admin.site.register(Post)

Comment: did you add it "after" you had initially ran a syncdb?

Comment: I don't remember. Probably I have ran it before. Now I deleted the database file and ran again. It created the table magically. Thanks a lot.

Comment: In the syncdb link read this section: "Syncdb will not alter existing tables" It will put things into perspective for you

Comment: I will be vary grateful if somebody briefly explains how syncdb works ?

Comment: I have posted the link of syncdb source code in the answer. Go through that. It is very self explanatory. No magic  :)

Answer (score 0):

Edit the proj1/settings.py file again, and change the INSTALLED_APPS setting to include the string 'forum'. So it’ll look like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    ......
    'forum',
)
```

and in models.py write model class
    Example:-

```
from django.db import models
class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
```

after writing model then u run syncdb command

Note:- you have written admins.py but file name should be admin.py, so check it again